# undefined local variable or method `controller_path' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x0000000febb0b8> Did you mean? controller_name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am getting this error on my rails application, i don't know where I called the controller_path that is undefined.

This is my `session_controller.rb`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def new
      super
    end

    def create
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      if !session[:return_to].blank?
        redirect_to session[:return_to]
        session[:return_to] = nil
      else
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      end
    end
  end
```

The error is pointing at line 7

```
self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
```

I dont know why or where I called what the error is referencing.

My full stacktrace is

```
    devise (4.4.3) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:48:in `auth_options'
devise (4.4.3) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:19:in `create'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.10) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.10) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.10) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.10) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.10) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.10) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

I just edited my question to include the stacktrace. Please let me know if there is any more of my code I have to post for you to completely help me trace my unknown error.

Comment: The stack trace will tell you where this was called. Please post it.

Comment: I don't know why or where you called what the error is referencing either, because you didn't share the full error message. **Always** show the full error message when asking questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: My bad, I have edited the question with the stack trace.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.4.3/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L48) is where the error is occurring.. However I also am unsure why this error would occur since `controller_path` is a method of Rails `AbstractController::Base` which `ApplicationController` inherits from and by default `DeviseController` inherits from `ApplicationController`. Are you certain you haven't made any other unconventional changes to devise?

Comment: Given the nature of your change from the default code have you considered avoiding modifying the devise controller and rather implementing a custom redirection instead a la [How To: redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Comment: I may have made a few changes, the only one I remember is changing the email field to be able to use something other than an email, i.e use a username. All i did was change the email regexp field in `devise.rb`

Comment: I find it a bit weird how you've defined a custom `SessionsController#create` action, and yet it's **not used**! The application is still referencing the default `Devise::SessionsController`. Did you update the `routes.rb` file to reference your custom action?

Comment: In fact, I don't understand why you claimed the error was on line 7 (`self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)`) at all - this isn't mentioned in the stack trace? Could the answer simply be that you need to restart the rails server? Perhaps it's in a weird state, where you're hitting a controller action that does not have a corresponding path?

Comment: I am just trying to fix it, so i tried to different things; 1.) Created a custom sessions controller and updated the routes then ran it. 2.) Used the default sessions controller. The latter was the stack trace i posted and the former is the stack trace that points to line 7. But both cases yield the same error.

Comment: Can you post the content of `def auth_options` at line 48?

Comment: Did you update your `routes.rb`  when you used your `SessionsController`?